# Glade/Gtkmm : Multiple window project

Tags: gtk, glade

I am currently discovering glade 3 with gtkmm and I am wondering how to create a multiple window project. For example if i want to generate a dialog Message when a button is clicked in a the main window. Can someone help me please !

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on advices in the internet, I already implemented a GUI using python by: a) creating a single glade file containing several windows (main, secondary, messages) all differently named in the glade file for further use

```
builder = gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("/home/onesinglefile.glade")
```

b) example of 1 "dialog_exitconfirm" message dialog, in the python script, it is initiated as object with `self.exitdialog = builder.get_object("dialog_exitconfirm")`
c) later in the script, use `self.exitdialog.show()` and `self.exitdialog.hide()` in order to pop up oder make it hiding/closing